# Eloquent query to get users who have employee role and first or last name contains characters

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trying to get all users that are employees and whose first or last name contain certain characters.

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles',function($query){ $query->where('title','Employee'); })->where('firstname','LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->orWhere('lastname','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->take(5)->get();
```

There is pivot table linking users to roles: role_user

Tried the above, it however returns all users which contain the string to match, not just those that have an 'Employee' role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you're adding an orWhere() which disables the first where's, so it filters on role and fistname or only on the lastname.

What you should have is this:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($query) { 
    $query->where('roles.title', 'Employee');
})->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
->orWhereHas('roles', function($query) { 
    $query->where('roles.title', 'Employee');
})->where('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
->get();
```

Which you can also write like this:

```
User::where(function($query) use ($term) {
    $query->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
          ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
})->whereHas('roles', function($query) use ($term) { 
    $query->where('roles.title', 'Employee');
});
```

Comment: I am using a pivot table. Don't actually have role_id foreign key on user model

Comment: Yeah, works. Though the join statement below seems a little more efficient. Wondering why is the orWhereHas clause needed and doing the same filtering logic as the first WhereHas

Comment: That last one throws an error 'undefined variable 'term'. Very odd as $term is defined and populated. Perhaps some new function context is created..

Comment: Forgot to add the use statement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do the job and is the most compact and efficient query I have come up with so far.

```
       $users = User::join('role_user','users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
       ->join('roles', function($join) { $join->on('role_user.role_id','=' ,'roles.id')
         ->where('roles.title','=','Employee'); })
            ->where('firstname','LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->orWhere('lastname','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->take(5)->get();
```